# how to solve the error of "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'zip'"

Tags: python, numpy

```
import sys

print(sys.version)

import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 

mean1=[np.random.randint(50),np.random.randint(50)]

mean2=[np.random.randint(50),np.random.randint(50)]

cov = [[100,0],[0,100]]

x1,y1= np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1,cov,100).T

x2,y2= np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2,cov,100).T

x=np.append(x1,x2)

y=np.append(y1,y2)
```

here i am facing the issue bellow line it reflecting zip issue i tried with the help of

```
X=np.array(zip(x,y))  # this line is showing the 

kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=2)

kmeans.fit(X)
```

Comment: In py3, `zip` is a unevaluated generator.  It has the expanded with `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert it into a datatype that np.array understands. So for example this should work:

```
X=np.array(list(zip(x,y)))
```